# Docker not able to run Java app

Tags: java, docker

I have the following project directory structure:

```
myapp/
    grails-app/ (its a grails app, derrrr)
    target/
        myapp.jar (built by grails)
    myapp.yml
```

...where `target/myapp.jar` is the executable JAR (actually a self-contained web app running embedded Jetty), and where `myapp.yml` is a config file required at startup.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM java:8
MAINTAINER My Name <myname@example.com>

WORKDIR /

ADD ./target/myapp.jar /myapp.jar
ADD ./myapp.yml /myapp.yml

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar myapp.jar myapp.yml"]
```

I then build the image with `docker build -t myapp .`. It builds successfully I then try to run the image via `docker run myapp` and get:

```
Unrecognized option: -jar myapp.jar myapp.yml
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here, and what I need to do to fix this or troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're giving all your parameters as one single parameter, but they are distinct. You should do

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "myapp.jar", "myapp.yml"]
```